# How to figure out the changeset a TFS 2015 build was build from?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-2015

I am distributing only binaries which were built by one of my TFS build definitions and each build receives a unique version number (1.0.$yy$dayofyear.$rev). The name of the build name contains this version number. The version number is set by a PowerShell script as the assembly version and the file version of the binary. I have only a build result rentention (including the built binaries in my drop folder) of 60 days and now I am wondering: How would I possibly figure out for some version number which is one year old which changeset it was built from so that I can have a look at the source code or rebuild exactly the binary? Do I have to add the changeset info somehow during my build explicitly? Do I have to encode the changeset number in my version number which is set during the build? Both ideas don't seem very ingenious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with a PowerShell script that I hook into my build definition as an additional build step just after a step that is similar to the one proposed [here](https://intovsts.net/2015/08/24/tfs-build-2015-and-versioning/) which sets the version attribute in all `AssemblyInfo.cs` files:

```
$systDefinitionId = $env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID
$buildDefVersion = $env:BUILD_DEFINITIONVERSION
$buildDefName = $env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME
$buildSourceVersion = $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION
$buildSourceBranch = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH

$SrcPath = $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY
$AllVersionFiles = Get-ChildItem $SrcPath AssemblyInfo.cs -recurse
$AllVersionFilesCount = ($AllVersionFiles | Measure-Object).Count

Write-Verbose "Updating $AllVersionFilesCount AssemblyInfo.cs files in path ""$SrcPath"" with source information."  -Verbose

Write-Verbose "ID of build definition:      $systDefinitionId" -Verbose
Write-Verbose "Version of build definition: $buildDefVersion" -Verbose
Write-Verbose "Name of build definition:    $buildDefName" -Verbose
Write-Verbose "Changeset to build:          $buildSourceVersion" -Verbose
Write-Verbose "Branch to build from:        $buildSourceBranch" -Verbose

foreach ($file in $AllVersionFiles)
{
(Get-Content $file.FullName) |
    %{$_ -replace 'AssemblyProduct\(""\)', "AssemblyProduct(""$buildDefName / $buildSourceVersion"")" } |
    %{$_ -replace 'AssemblySourceBranch\(""\)', "AssemblySourceBranch(@""$buildSourceBranch"")" } |
    %{$_ -replace 'AssemblySourceChangeset\(0\)', "AssemblySourceChangeset($buildSourceVersion)" } |
    %{$_ -replace 'AssemblyBuild\(""\)', "AssemblyBuild(@""$buildDefName / ID: $systDefinitionId / Version: $buildDefVersion"")" } |
Set-Content $file.FullName -Force
}
```

I am modifying the `AssemblyProduct` attribute by writing into it the build definition name and the changeset which was used to create the binaries. Later on this info is visible on the properties of the exe or dll in Windows Explorer on the details tab.

Moreover I have defined the custom attributes `AssemblySourceBranch`, `AssemblySourceChangeset` and `AssemblyBuild` to carry more detailed info. They all have the same structure, so for brevity only the source code of `AssemblySourceChangeset`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AssemblySourceChangesetAttribute : Attribute
{
  public AssemblySourceChangesetAttribute(uint changeset)
  {
    Changeset = changeset;
  }

  public uint Changeset { get; }
}
```

Should the info in the "publicly" visible product field not be enough to be able to rebuild the binary, one can still result to reflecting upon the exe or dll and read those custom attributes which have info on the source branch, the id and the version of the build definiton stored.

Comment: Always better when you fix it yourself，as the solution is most fit your scenario !:)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a powershell script or [extension task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-GenerateReleaseNotes-Task) which will generate release notes as part of TFS vNext build. You will get something as below:

[image]

And then you could store it, for the source code take a look at this [blog](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2016/03/01/A-vNext-build-task-and-PowerShell-script-to-generate-release-notes-as-part-of-TFS-vNext-build)

Comment: I prefer some storage of the info "version-changeset" either directly in the binary or in the TFS. Release notes could easily get lost, because someone copies only the binaries to some other place. Yet it is an interesting mechanism for documenting associated workitems and commits. Will try to remember your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

*Preface: XAML builds.*

You can have visibility into all your build products by creating release/hotfix branches, and having build definitions specific to those branches. It's easy enough to clone a build to a branch, and use version numbers as part of your binary stamps. I prefer to use a branch version number approach, and stamp my binaries with that version number. As long as you're creating unique build definitions for the binaries in each branch, you'll be able to easily view past builds, and see exactly what changesets are associated with it.All you need is the binary's version number, and you'll be able to trace it back to source easily.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I prefaced that in my answer. :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am working with vNext build definitions.

Comment: The same basic principles of branching and having a build for that branch apply. Since retention rules are so strict, I'd recommend retaining the released builds. If you have the build definition, you'll know what branch the solution is in, and you'll be able to view the history and correlate with the binary's build date/time.

Comment: What is your suggestion in terms of the number of retention days? Is there a possibility to configure the build so that the "meta" info is kept while the binaries in the drop location get removed after some days? That would be an optional solution for me as well.

Comment: Yes, if you create a branch and follow a naming convention for that branch and the builds for that branch, AND you stamp your binaries using that same convention, then you can reference the deployed binaries, which would lead you back to the branch and build that created them.