# Character C being prepended to changeset number in batched continuous integration TFS builds

Tags: c#, powershell, tfs-2015

I have enabled gated check-in in my build definition. I was wondering why the check-in builds succeeds whereas the following batched continuous integration build fails.

I have a powershell script step in my build definition which places the changeset the build is build from in an C# Assembly attribute which takes only an int. I figured out that the integration build fails, because the `$env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION` I use in my powershell script has a 'C' prepended to the changeset number when in continuous Integration. The consequence is that `[assembly: SourceChangeSet(C123456)]` of course is not tolerated by the C# compiler and the compilation fails which makes the build fail.

Why is that 'C' prepended? Is this on purpose and if so, what is the purpose?

**EDIT**

This is the powershell script code:

```
$buildSourceVersion = $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION.TrimStart("C")
$SrcPath = $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY
$AllVersionFiles = Get-ChildItem $SrcPath AssemblyInfo.cs -recurse

Write-Verbose "Changeset to build:          $buildSourceVersion" -Verbose

foreach ($file in $AllVersionFiles)
{
(Get-Content $file.FullName) |
    %{$_ -replace 'AssemblySourceChangeset\(0\)', "AssemblySourceChangeset($buildSourceVersion)" } |
Set-Content $file.FullName -Force
}
```

The C# attribute is declared as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AssemblySourceChangesetAttribute : Attribute
{
  public AssemblySourceChangesetAttribute(uint changeset)
  {
    Changeset = changeset;
  }

  public uint Changeset { get; }
}
```

My AssemblyInfo.cs file contains before script run: `[assembly: SourceChangeSet(0)]`.

My AssemblyInfo.cs file contains after script run: `[assembly: SourceChangeSet(123456)]`. However in the case of an batched continuous integration build it is `[assembly: SourceChangeSet(C123456)]`.

Comment: I don't think anyone here can diagnose a problem with code we can't see.

Comment: What code would you like to see? The attribute class definition? The powershell script?

Comment: The PowerShell script would be a good start, as well as some sample input (what it's working with) and output (what it produces)

Comment: See my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147361/how-to-figure-out-the-changeset-a-tfs-2015-build-was-build-from) where I have both the powershell script and the C# attribute code posted.

Comment: each Q&A should be self-contained. Please don't ask people to follow your post history just to diagnose your code. That other post could disappear or be edited. And on mobile it's difficult to manage multiple posts

Comment: @alroc See my edit which now contains source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix "C" means the Source Version is changeset. For example C123 means changeset 123 to build.
[image]

I can reproduce the behavior you meet with CI in TFS2015 but it has been changed in TFS2017. In TFS2017, the source version does not have a prefix "C" anymore when then build is triggered from CI. So I would recommend to upgrade your TFS Server to the latest version to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why it's there is something you would have to ask Microsoft about. The note for `$env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION` on [visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables) says:

> The latest version control change that is included in this build.
>
> Git: The commit ID.
>
> TFVC: the changeset.

Which makes me think that it might be there so you can identify whether it is a Git-repository (C123 = Commit123) or a TFVC-repository (CS123 = ChangeSet123).

You can remove both using regex, ex:

```
$changset = $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION -replace '^C|^CS'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am using `$env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION.TrimStart("C")` to get rid of the prepended 'C' before placing it into the attribute. But my question was about the why and the purpose of it.

Comment: See update. I don't have access to any repos. so I'm just guessing on the example values.

Comment: I am on TFS and the prefix is 'C' - but only for batched continuous integration builds.

Comment: Ok. I assumed TFS used CS as some other posts I found had to remove CS ;)